# VBA project can not detect foreign letters

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I try to take data from an xlsx document which consists of letters like "ö ü İ" and etc. I get some error.

I have already tried to change the language of the program also the changing language for non-Unicode programs. It did not work

```
Sub Getdataclosed()    
    Dim src As Workbook        
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ciyican\Desktop\Daily_LU31_DM_Report\nameofthebook.xlsx", True, True)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate        
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:d26").Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d8:G32").Formula        
    
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ciyican\Desktop\Daily_LU31_DM_Report\nameofthebook.xlsx ", True, True)

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets("Waste Claculation").Range("h3").Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("k7").Formula
End Sub
```

> Application defined or object defined error

Comment: ① What are you trying to do with that code? Please describe with words. ② Where did you get this error? ③ What is the formula in `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d8:G32")` and `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("k7")`?

Comment: Is the name of one of your sheets really "Waste Claculation"? Sounds like a typo. And why do you open the same file 2 times?

Comment: First of all thank you for your replies. I am trying to copy some values from 2 "different" books that I can download. For copying from closed books I am using the functions that you can see upper part in my code. The typo is a mistake I can understand bu the Major issue is that I can not copy anything from a file which has foreign letters. The name of my file is originally "Üretim İzleme". So whenever I try to put this file name in my code I get an error that I mentioned earlier.So basically the VBA can not read foreign languages. I do not know how to make vba reads files with foreign letters